# Can SVM solution change after shuffling the inputs?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm

When training a support vector machine (SVM) for classification with exactly the same data I obtain **different results based on the order of the inputs,** ie. if I shuffle the data I get different SVMs.

If I understood the theory correctly, the SVM solution should be the same regardless of the order of the inputs, so how come I get the different results? Is there any implementation "detail" in SVM why shuffling would change the solution? I have already checked my code several times, because I think this smells.

I use the SVM implementation in OpenCV.

**EDIT:** in this case, by shuffling I refer to changing the order of the data points not features.

Comment: You changed the order of the features *and* the labels together, right?

Comment: Oh, that could be it! Good thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the OpenCV implementation. But do this: run several trials on *exactly the same data set* -- no shuffling, same order, same data points. See if the SVM changes. Obviously, in theory, it shouldn't. But it could be that there is some small randomization step somewhere in the implementation that produces different outputs for the same input.

Edit: As Chris A. asks, do the feature vectors correspond to their proper labels after shuffling? If not, that would obviously destroy your results.

Comment: Thanks for the idea for testing, tommorow i get back to the data and check it.

Comment: In the end it took me longer than expected, and the outcome is not what I hoped for. Same data, same order does not change the results. If there is any randomization involved that was causing the differences I observed, it is order-dependent. Unfortunately(?!), I am no longer getting the large differences as before, so i tend to think, it is some hideous coding error of mine:/

Comment: ...when I learn more about the (non)-existence of the randomization in the SVM learning algorithm, or I discover the supposed bug, I update the question. This was the most helpful post, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. No worries; we all have experienced the same thing, where something doesn't work, and then miraculously, it does work.

Answer (score 1):

SVM is for solving convex optimization problem, so maximum is unique. That means any random optimization algorithms will solve problem very close to unique optimal solution. And shuffling can't change result above float-point operation accuracy.