# Accuracy changed with shuffling training dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I'm using `TfidfVectorizer` to use `svm` under `sklearn` package.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_Train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_Train)

classifier = svm.LinearSVC()
classifier.fit(X_Train, Y_Train)
```

But, there is a problem I'm facing. When I shuffle training dataset, I get different accuracy.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677119/can-svm-solution-change-after-shuffling-the-inputs)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Answer is  not clear there

Comment: Why would you not expect that accuracty is different if you train using different training data?

Comment: I'm not using different training data. I'm just shuffling data.. @EdChum

Comment: @AerofoilKite Can you add more code to your question with minimum data to reproduce the problem?